# Is it possible to restore SQL Server 2016 backup on SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to restore SQL Server 2016 backup on SQL Server 2014?

Specifically we are using TFS SQL backups

Comment: Do you have tried? Was it possible? did you get any error?

Comment: At least make sure that database compatibility level is SQL server 2014 or lower